# Remove "NUL" characters in txt file with windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a large text file with millions of lines where I need to remove "NUL" characters (showing that way in Notepad++, see pic). Search and replace \0 works in Notepad++ but takes forever. I wonder how I could remove these NUL characters with a windows command that would probably work faster?

[image]

Comment: Write a little utility to read the file and create a new one without the NUL bytes. It should be quick to write, and quick to run. I am suprised that you can even load a file with 'millions of lines' into Notepad++, it is not all that graceful with large files.

Comment: Actually every solution will take time, as it's _milions of lines_, so program/script has to read file content (load it into memory) and change the given characters

Comment: Are you sure that you do not just have a Unicode UTF-16 file?

Comment: I would advise that your file is corrupted, because line 688664, clearly does not follow the 'every other character is NUL' pattern shown in the other lines of your image. BTW, you may find that a simple `Type "file.ext" 1>"file.fix"` will help, but please be aware that with so many lines, you'd really need some way of validating each is correct before accepting the new file as fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the PowerShell approach instead of cmd one if you can, it'll be much quicker.

Run this in cmd:

```
powershell -c "(Get-Content .\file.txt) -replace '\x00+', '' | Set-Content .\file.txt"
```

This can be problematic with files 1GB+ as it loads the file into memory and I'd recommend using a full-blown PowerShell here.

In order to achieve it quicker you can use .NET streams within the PowerShell:

```
#Open file.txt
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText("file.txt")
#Save the output to file2.txt (can't save to the same files, as it is locked by StreamReader
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList ("file2.txt")

#loop over lines in file and replace char
while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
    #Replace null character with empty string
    $writer.WriteLine(($line.Replace('\0', "")))
}

#Close both streams
$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
```

Saving 400MB file with almost 2 million lines took ~6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I found that if each line has a known text string, you can use the FIND command (not findstr though) and redirect output back to a file.  FIND will "eat" any null chars in the strings.

so in your data, say each line is terminated with or contains a '.' char you can use:
FIND "." inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt to eliminate the nulls.

findstr wont work because it will print the string as found on input.

Comment: if that works (not verified), `find /v ""` should  work without depending on "a defined char in each line"

Comment: Thank You.  I did find that it may be replaceing the NULL with an EOL, not "eating" it so this solution may only work if the null is last char on the line.